# How do I get from Terminal 1 to Terminal 2 in Hong Kong airport? (HKG)

Tags: airports, hong-kong, hkg

My flight is at Terminal 2 at the Hong Kong airport but I cannot find any local buses to get there, only to Terminal 1.

I also have looked up information on [their website](https://www.hongkongairport.com/eng/passenger/arrival/t1/airport-services-facilities/in-terminal-transport.html) but it is ambiguous as to whether going from 1 to 2 is possible:

> The Automated People Mover (APM) takes passengers from Terminal 2 to Terminal 1 and between Terminal 1 and SkyPier. Travelling at more than 63 kilometres per hour, this driverless electric train system carries about 7,200 passengers per hour and departs every two to four minutes.

Based on this information... it feels really far that they need a 63 km/h train to go between the terminals, so **how do I go between Terminal 1 and 2**?

Comment: The furthest gates of T1 and T2 are some way apart. The entrances for passengers are about 100m apart, separated by the railway station. You can walk between them entirely indoors

Comment: Never used T2, but it was my understanding that T2 actually only had the check-in/ticketing/security facilities, and that flights (gates) were actually all in T1? So if you're ticketed through, you wouldn't actually need to go to T2 at all...

Comment: T2 only has check-in and all the gates are in T1 or the SkyPier.  The Automated People Mover is for people who *have checked-in and passed security* to go to the gates in T1 or the SkyPier.

Answer (score 5):

2023 Update: Terminal 2 had been completely demolished and is being rebuilt.

Simple, you walk.

The distance between the two terminals are only about 100m apart.

[image]

Comment: The reason HKG is like this is because Terminal 2 has no boarding gates.  After checking-in, you then basically go to Terminal 1's gates and board the plane.  I think this is a unique airport where going to the wrong Terminal doesn't cost you more than 15 minutes to correct...